# Convert from UNIX Timestamp to "Today at: currentTime" using Java

Tags: java, android

I've tried to convert a UNIX Timestamp to todays date time.

Like I have a simple UNIX Timestamp and then I want to convert it like this:

*Today at: theTimeFromMyTimestamp*

Anyone that has a correct solution for this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this `DateFormat.getDateFormat(mContext).format(new Date(myTimestamp * 1000))`

As `new Date()` requires milliseconds instead of seconds, you have to multiple by 1000

Comment: Remember that myTimestamp needs to be a long integer, otherwise it will probably wrap around to negative when you multiply by 1000.

Answer (score 4):

You can also have a tighter control of the final format by making it explicit. It also avoids creating a Date object and needs no context:

```
DateFormat.format("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ssaa", myTimeStamp * 1000L);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert the timestamp milisecond to `long int` by adding a `L` in the multiplication:

```
DateFormat.getDateFormat(mContext).format(new Date(myTimestamp * 1000L))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * Get the human readable String representation of time
 * @param unix_time
 * @return String format of time eg 13:20
 * @throws NullPointerException
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException
 */
public String convertFromUnix(String unix_time) throws NullPointerException, IllegalArgumentException{
    long time = Long.valueOf(unix_time);
    String result = "";
    Date date = new Date(time);
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    result = format.format(date);
    Log.d("date", format.format(date));

    return result;
}
```