# SimpleDateFormat giving wrong date in android

Tags: java, android, date, datetime

I've seen

> [Convert from UNIX Timestamp to "Today at: currentTime" using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802950/convert-from-unix-timestamp-to-today-at-currenttime-using-java)
>
> [Convert unix time stamp to date in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17432735/convert-unix-time-stamp-to-date-in-java)

but none of these is working for me.

I have a timestamp : `1503037706145`

And I'm using the following code to convert it to a readable date:

```
Long leadTime = leadData.getLong("addedOn");

Date date = new Date(leadTime*1000);
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy  |  hh:mm a");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Calcutta"));
String formattedDate = sdf.format(date);
```

It's returning  `15/05/49599 11:25:45PM`

But when I check it on [this](https://www.epochconverter.com/), it returns `Friday, 18 August 2017 07:00:14.817`

which is correct. What am I doing wrong ??

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleTextFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: thanks @BasilBourque , I didn't know that. I'll see the tutorial :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timestamp you currently have is OK for Android. The fact that you need to multiply it by 1000 to make it work on www.epochconverter.com, indicates that epochconverter uses a different format. Just throw `leadTime` in Date and you should be fine.

Comment: Timestamps are in milliseconds and OP's stamp is in milliseconds. The conclusion of *1000 not required is correct anyway.

Comment: @laalto. OK, I'll update that. I always thought that it were seconds. I thought epochconverter.com (the linked site) used milliseconds

Comment: and @laalto, how do you figure out whether ts is in seconds or milliseconds ?

Comment: @0xDEADC0DE you're right. OP's timestamp is in millis so the *1000 is not needed. 1503037706 is the seconds value. Removing the *1000 is the answer.

Comment: The timestamp has 3 more digits than a seconds-based timestamp would have. epochconverter can guess that such timestamps are in milliseconds, even if normally it would use seconds as input.

Comment: When you put OP's timestamp into Epoch converter it shows this message "Assuming that this timestamp is in milliseconds". The converter knows that a millisecond value was input and is converting it to seconds.

Answer (score 2):

Other Answers are correct about not needing to multiply your count-from-epoch by a thousand as you already have a number in milliseconds.

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

But the other Answers and the Question all use troublesome classes that are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes. See [*Oracle Tutorial*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

## java.time

For Android, see the ThreeTen-Backport and ThreeTenABP projects.

`Instant` is a moment on timeline in UTC resolved to nanoseconds.

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( 1503037706145 ) ;  // Instant is a moment on timeline in UTC resolved to nanoseconds.
String output = instant.toString() ;  // Generate string in standard ISO 8601 format.
```

Assign a time zone if desired.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using `DateFormat.format("MMM dd, hh:mm a", timeInMillisec * 1000)` as some versions of android won't support `SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: You saved my day. That was the only thing which helped.